# Azure Webapp domain binding restarts the Webapp

Tags: azure, web-applications, binding, dns, restart

We have an Azure webapp that can host multiple tenants.

Tenant creation is done through the webapp itself, each tenant gets their own domain beneath a main domain (eg tenant1.awesomestuff.com)

Our issue is that even though we have setup Azure Traffic Manager with a primary and redundant Webapp that when tenants are added the act of performing the domain binding to the Webapp restarts the Webapp (I expect since it is modifying the web.config behind the scenes).

This is becoming more and more of a problem as tenant creation interrupts realtime tenants using their own systems.

Using Traffic Manager to switch to redundant Webapp is not a solution since the detection of the primary webapp going down takes too long, we need a way of telling Azure to use the redundant Webapp when we create the tenant, wait for the primary webapp to restart and come back up before switching back to it.

We do have some code in Application_Startup that is causing some of the delay, but we have profiled this and there is more time spent else where that is causing most of the delay.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Why not just add a wildcard domain under your webapp (*.example.com)? - See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-a-wildcard-domain. Then have your app logic check which domains you should really answer for.

Comment: wow, thats fantastic @evilSnobu did not know I could add the wildcard domain to the Webapp like that - many many thanks